# Как отсортировать словарь по значениям ключей, если эти значения могут повторяться?

Tags: python, сортировка, dict, словарь

Имеется словарь, где ключ - слово в тексте, а его значение - количество раз, которое оно встречается в нём. Причем разные слова могут встречаться одинаковое число раз. Как можно отсортировать в таком случае слова в порядке уменьшения их частоты?

Comment: `for el in sorted(dict_.items(), key=lambda el:-el[1]):
 print(el) ` `dict_` это ваш словарь

Comment: @Danis А «минус» зачем? Доморощенный трюк `reverse=True`? И почему не пользоваться `itemgetter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for el in sorted(dict_.items(), key=lambda el:-el[1]):
    print(el)
```

`dict_` - это ваш словарь

Comment: А «минус» зачем? Доморощенный трюк `reverse=True`? И почему не пользоваться `itemgetter`?

Comment: @0andriy не охото импортировать модуль `operators` ради одного метода

Comment: Но это же вырвано из контекста, оригинал наверняка больше.

Comment: Danis Зачем импортировать модуль? Когда можно импортировать функцию?